# Second-order separation schema in Zermelo and Zermelo--Fraenkel

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, axioms

It is a nice theorem of Zermelo that if we replace the Replacement schema with its second-order counterpart, "The image of a set under *any* function is again a set", then we necessarily get a model isomorphic to some $V_\kappa$ for an inaccessible $\kappa$.

> What happens when we take $\sf Z$, i.e. $\sf ZFC$ without Replacement (but with Separation), and replace the Separation schema with its second-order counterpart: "If $A$ is any collection of sets, then for every $x$, $\{u\in x\mid u\in A\}$ is a set"?

If we add first-order Replacement back, one can see immediately that any model has to be well-founded. Once we have a rank function, an ill-founded model implies there is a set of ordinals of the model without a minimum. Since this set is internally bounded by some ordinal, the second-order axiom implies that this witness is in fact internal to the model.

So in particular, every model of this $\sf ZFC_{1.5}$-hybrid, is isomorphic to a unique transitive model. But this is not all. If $x$ is any set in such transitive model, and $y\subseteq x$, then applying second-order Separation we get that $y$ is also a member of the model. So power sets are computed correctly. Therefore it is necessarily the case that the model is some $V_\alpha$, and since it satisfies $\sf ZFC$ this is necessarily a worldly $\alpha$.

(And easily it can be seen that if $\alpha$ is a worldly cardinal, then $V_\alpha$ satisfies this $\sf ZFC_{1.5}$.)

> What happened with the second-order Zermelo (which I will avoid denoting by $\sf Z_2$ for obvious reasons)?

Specifically, since there is no rank function what can we say about this theory?

Comment: Is your first paragraph about ZFC?

Comment: Yes, it is about ZFC. The proof, by the way, is as follows: (1) Show the model is well-founded, essentially as I have shown here, but using Replacement to directly pick a sequence of ordinals; now we can assume the model is transitive (2) Show that power sets are computed correctly by showing that if $A$ is in the model, every subset of $A$ is the image of some class function applied to $A$; so our model is some $V_\alpha$, finally (3) show that the ordinals have to be regular, and thus $\alpha$ is inaccessible.

Comment: Huh. Thanks. It works with Separation as well, at least steps (1) and (2), so we do get a worldly cardinal.

Comment: "What's this here?", he says, pointing to a random point on the page. In the ensuing excitement...

Comment: Do you have the foundation axiom in your version of Zermelo? The way you described it, it seems as if you want to include it, but many versions of Z do not. If you don't have it, then it would seem to open the door to all kinds of strange models.

Comment: For what it's worth, I find it to be a more interesting question with the foundation axiom included, which seems to be what you had intended.

Comment: @Joel: I have a reverse deja vu, did I once or twice made the same remark to you about Z and Foundation? :)

Comment: Yes, it was from you that I learned that Z should not include foundation, although we both seem to find it more natural to include it!

Comment: @Joel: I guess that for me it is context dependent. And I think that when I wrote this, at least the revision, I had in mind the case without Foundation. But I'll take any answer, actually.

Comment: @Joel: I imagine that the proof in my question would show that any model of second-order Zermelo (with Foundation) is isomorphic to some $V_\alpha$ for a limit ordinal $\alpha>\omega$. Which is nice, but now comes the fact that without Foundation there are some pretty weird models out there. And I wonder how much does the second-order axiom affects these.

Comment: Why must they have the form $V_\alpha$? I don't see this. It seems to me that there can be strange transitive models of second-order Zermelo+foundation that are not of the form $V_\alpha$.

Comment: @Joel: They compute power sets correctly.

Comment: Yes, of course, but so what? Why can't there be sets of rank  $\omega+\omega$ and higher, say, without $\omega+\omega$ existing?

Comment: @Joel: Ugh, yeah. I keep forgetting about these whenever it suits me. :P

Comment: In fact, can't we build models of your theory like this:  Take any V_lambda for limit ordinal $\lambda>\omega+\omega$. Now, throw out all sets that contain $\omega+\omega$ in their transitive closure. Call what's left M. This is a transitive set, and computes power sets correctly, and satisfies the power set axiom, and unions etc., right? And it has sets of rank above $\omega+\omega$. So it seems to have second-order Zermelo, but is not $V_\alpha$ for any $\alpha$. Is it right?

Comment: @Joel: Yes, the standard "weird models of Z" seem to work. Now I wonder if having second-order separation is equivalent to having correct power sets.

Comment: Isn't that obvious? If you have all subsets, then you definitely satisfy separation. And with second-order separation, you get all subsets.

Comment: @Joel: Yeah, you're right. I'm just hungry and my brain functions at lower capacity. I think it's time to get some food... :)